# How to create custom methods that use prefix as argument

Tags: javascript, oop, methods

Learning JavaScript OOP ... And being all day on that field but... 
I cannot understand / find **how to create custom JS Method** just like

`.toString()` , `.toUpperCase()` ...and other methods, that for e.g. if you have an accessed object like

```
customer.name // John
```

and you use:

```
customer.name.toLowerCase();
```

will give you `// john`

That means that a function Method `toLowerCase()` somehow uses the `this` reference of the *prefixed object* as the *operable argument* for the `return` operation.

**How to do something like that? Attach a method that will do some stuff with some unknown previous object?**

OK, just a stupid example, let's say we want to be able to create a `.addLength()` Method that will simply allow us to do: `customer.name.addLength() // John Name length = 4`

```
function addLength(){   
    var that = this;
    var name = that.toString();
    return ( name +' Name length = '+ name.length );   
}
```

ok, this is totally wrong I know, it was just to describe somehow. 
 It's not for a purpose, just to understand. (better useful examples are welcome) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to make use of protoypal inheritance

https://stackoverflow.com/a/572996

http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html

Comment: But how can I access an object prototype if I don't know anything about the previous object? I just want to create a `.addLength()` Method for some **unknown** prefixed object. Just like normal JS methods. I'm a bit lost. Thanks

Comment: Object.prototype.addLength = function() { return this.length; } ---- this will add the addLength method to the prototype of the Object object..which every new object will refer to..read the links I posted - especially the one on prototypal inheritance